# nodevars.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, tfsbuild, apache-cordova

I'm getting this strange nodejs error when trying to build my project on a TFS Build server.

Can someone explain me why I'm getting this error?
I get this error for all my Cordova Tools projects, during TFS build.

Thanks a lot!

```
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
> (287): '"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"\nodevars.bat' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command,  C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
> (287): operable program or batch file.  C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
> (287): '"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"\node' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command,  C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
> (287): operable program or batch file.  C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets
> (287): Error installing local npm package.
```

Comment: It looks like your nodejs instalation folder is not in enviroment variable PATH check this helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/ to see if it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Thanks to Molda, a litle bit.. 
The wrong installation folder was in the environment variable.

It refered to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs

and it was installed in

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

Thanks Molda!

Comment: what is the name of the environment variable? After installing Nodejs, I did not see any environment variable being created.